# Need Testing in node.js

Tags: node.js, testing

I'm quite new to testing in javascript, where I work, we us node.js for our projects.

I finished one of our projects, but I only used manual testing.
I need to develop my testing skill and I dont know how to improve it.

I need any testing tool to run my node.js projects, could you please tell me how to improve and learn new testing skills?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Mocha test framework](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/). I think this is the best choose for testing node.js applications at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Node to develop a web application you could use one of the headless browsers to test the user interaction (along with ajax) there are [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and [Zombie](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) for example.

Look around in [Node Toolbox](http://toolbox.no.de/categories/Testing) you'll find many frameworks and utilities to create your tests.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good overview on some of the different unit test tools for Node.js:

[3 Quick Tips for Writing Tests in Node.Js (after some rambling)](http://niallohiggins.com/2012/03/28/3-quick-tips-for-writing-tests-in-nodejs/)